# Non-45º triangle with aligned content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this design, originally sent in Photoshop format:
[image: Current design]

It has a gray triangle with a non-trivial angle and some divs that should be aligned with it.
Currently I use a transformation on a div and set the distances to each div manually. This is obviously a terrible solution and I can't know exactly the right width for the div.

What I have is:

CSS:

```
.triangulo {
    width: 300%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #e9ebeb;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(75deg);
    transform: rotate(75deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
...
<div class="block block-1">...</div>
<div class="block block-2">...</div>
<div class="triangulo show-for-medium-up">
```

Question is: How can I make this in a proper way? Each div should be X pixels to the right of the triangle at that height, the triangle must end at the bottom with an unknown height and I should be able to change the angle at will.

Comment: Your image doesn't exist.

Comment: It opens just fine here, must be cached then. I'll upload in another place and edit. Thank you.

Comment: It worked for me.  Without a fixed height, doing anything better than what you're doing is going to be hard. If the overall height is fixed, you could take advantage of the fact that percentage values for the `left` CSS property are computed relative to the parent container's height.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use a simple embedded SVG for the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about transforming the container, and then "undoing" the transformtion on each item?

For example (SCSS and no vendor prefixes for brevity) -

HTML:

```
<section class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div><i class="fa fa-bus"></i></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, autem tenetur?</p
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><i class="fa fa-bus"></i></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, autem tenetur?</p
    </li>
    <li>
      <div><i class="fa fa-bus"></i></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, autem tenetur?</p
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section.content {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 50px 100px;
  background: yellow;
/*   Turn the whole thing */
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  li {
    margin: 100px 0;
    /* Turn em back! */
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    div {
      float: left;
      background: green;
      padding: 25px;
      margin-right: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  }
}
```

It's going to have some weird margins to play with in order to move stuff around, but it beats manually positioning the element.

#### Here's a [codepen!](http://codepen.io/drewminns/pen/ByQXWN)

Party on dude.